# How do I insert Data Into database with many Input which has same name?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

hello friends I have a form field in which I want to insert data which has four field which are customer_id , field_name1 ,field_name2, field_name3 ,
The question is  I want to insert data which has many inputs but  same input name like field_name1  field_name2 field_name3 , firstly there is no input but when I click on a button add partner details then these inputs shows by javascript .
like field_name1,field_name2,field_name3 ten times can repeat , I want to insert data in database according to there numbers with same customer_id , but different field name  , below is my code , hope you understand it .

here is my code

```
    <?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","satya");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $customer_id=$_POST['customer_id'];
for ($ix=0; $ix<count($_POST['field_name1']); $ix++)
{
    $field_data = array(
        'field_name1' => $_POST['field_name1'][$ix],
        'field_name2' => $_POST['field_name2'][$ix],
        'field_name3' => $_POST['field_name3'][$ix],

    );
    $sql="INSERT INTO customer(customer_id,details1,details2,details3) VALUES('$customer_id','$field_name1','$field_name1','$field_name1')";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($result){
        echo "data has been inserted";
    }
    else{
        echo "data could not be inserted";
    }
}
}
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <div class="col-md-4" ></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="customer_id">Customer ID </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer_id" placeholder="customer_id">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
       </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="details1">details1 </label>
            </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="details2">details2</label>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="details3">details3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                 <div>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_partner btn btn-primary" title="Add Partner Details">Add Partner Details</a>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="partner_wrapper" >

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</form>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){



    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_partner'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.partner_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<span class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="field_name1[]" value=""/></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_name2[]" value=""/></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_name3[]" value=""/></div><button type="button" href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button btn btn-primary" title="Remove field">Remove</button></span>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('span').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: There is nothing inherent to a sql database that prevents you from adding records with with same customer id but different other field values

Comment: Can you post the structure of the `customer`  table?

Comment: You want a `UNQIUE` constraint? Maybe also see `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE / INSERT`?

Comment: thank you all guys , answer of barmer worked for me , thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the repeating fields array-style names:

```
<input type="text" name="field_name1[]">
```

PHP will collect the inputs into arrays, so `$_POST['field_name1']` will be an array. Then you can loop over them:

```
foreach ($_POST['field_name1'] AS $index => $field1) {
    $field2 = $_POST['field_name2'][$index];
    $field3 = $_POST['field_name3'][$index];

    // now you can insert all these values into the DB
}
```

Comment: thank you this code fully worked for me , but when I give a message that data has been added it is also showing many time

Comment: Don't put that message in the loop.